# Cucumber + Rspec + Rails + Webrat, factor_girl + autotest on MacOSX ... in gem.config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rspec, cucumber, autotest

I found example how to use on:

http://www.claytonlz.com/index.php/2009/04/how-to-setup-rspec-cucumber-webrat-rcov-and-autotest-on-leopard/

but I try to find solution to put this all gems to gem.config (enviroment.rb) with using
**gemcutter** gem repository (this is prefered gems repository now ?)

Maybe some one have properly configured gem.config dependency for:

**Cucumber + RSpec + Rails + Factor_Girl + Webrat ... autotest on MacOSX (with Growl)**

I want to have all needed gems in gem.config, maybe I expecting to much ;)

Regards,
Andrzej

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do the following

```
sudo gem install cucumber cucumber-rails rspec rspec-rails webrat database_cleaner factory_girl faker
./script/generate rspec
./script/generate cucumber --rspec --webrat
```

It will setup your config/environments/cucumber.rb
You can add the missing ones manually like I did below

```
config.gem 'database_cleaner', :lib => false, :version => '>=0.4.3' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vendor/plugins/database_cleaner'))
config.gem 'webrat',           :lib => false, :version => '>=0.6.0' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vendor/plugins/webrat'))
config.gem 'rspec-rails',      :lib => 'spec/rails', :version => '>=1.3.2' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vendor/plugins/rspec-rails'))
config.gem 'rspec',            :lib => 'spec', :version => '>=1.3.0' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vendor/plugins/rspec'))
config.gem 'cucumber'
config.gem 'cucumber-rails',   :lib => 'cucumber/rails', :version => '>=0.2.4' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vendor/plugins/cucumber-rails'))
config.gem "faker"
config.gem "factory_girl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `:source => "http://gemcutter.org"` to every config.gem line. I'm not sure if all gems are on Gemcutter already though!

Comment: current version not needed any more "gem tumble" command and gem using  "http://gemcutter.org" as default. But when I have all gems in gem.config I still have problems with running autotest. Some guys moves gem.config to enviroments/test.rb. Im still looking for best solution.